# woocommerce coupon round to 1 decimal

Tags: woocommerce, rounding

In my store I'm using this code to round off decimals in coupons.
Is it posible to round numbers from 99.555 to 99.9?
I need only one decimal.

```js
/**
 * Round off decimals for coupons
 **/
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $instance ) { 
    $discount = ceil( $discount );
    return $discount; 
}   
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function (instead of [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)) which has a `$precision` parameter which you can set to `1`. This will round up to the closets precision which for `9.555` is `9.6`:

```php
/**
* Round off decimals for coupons
**/

function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount, 
$discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $instance ) { 
    $discount = round( $discount, 1 );
    return $discount; 
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 
'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
```

If you want to convert `9.555` to `9.9`, then you'll have to create that logic, something like this for example:

```php
/**
* Round off decimals for coupons
**/

function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount, 
$discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $instance ) { 

    $disvount_floor = floor($discount);

    // This will return x.99 if $discount decimal number is > 0.5
    if (fmod($discount, $disvount_floor) > 0.5) {
        return "{$disvount_floor}.9";
    }

    return $discount; 

} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 
'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: The first one works perfect!
The second one returns:
syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: That is a syntax error, a missing parenthesis in the if, can't you see it? I updated the answer.